# MVC: AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some problems with creating two actions with the same name but 1 have a parameter and the other one not, I always get the this error:

**ERROR:**

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

These are my actions:

```
public IActionResult Skills(string skill)
{
   return View("SkillDetails");
}

public IActionResult Skills()
{
   return View("Skills");
}
```

These are my routes:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "WithSkill",
        template: "Home/Skills/{skill}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: What other routes do you have, and is the route you have shown before all other routes

Answer (score 2):

You can't differentiate by action parameters alone. Try renaming the action, or using an different HttpMethod if one is a Get and one is a Post. Or do something like this.

```
public IActionResult Skills(string skill)
{
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(skill)
      return View("Skill");
   return View("SkillDetails");
}
```